# How to increase the efficiency of iterating through data

Tags: python, pandas

I have python code which calls a couple of APIs to fetch data based on a product key.  What I have works but I am looking to determine a more efficient means to accomplish the desired outcome.  Where I lose the most efficiency and takes quite a long time is when I iterate over the columns to determine if they contain a list so that I can explode the list if found.  This snippet below is from another SO post, but even they were unsure about the efficiency of it.

There are 45 columns in the dataframe with the possibility of more being added when I next call the API so I need a dynamic way to discover what needs to be exploded versus creating a list of target columns to exploden and feeding that to the pandas explode fucntion.

```
    
    df_final = df.copy()
    for c in df.columns:
        if(isinstance(df[c][0],list)):
            df_final = df_final.explode(c)
    print(df_final.head(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Pandas 1.3.0, [you can pass in multiple columns to explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

```
# Find columns to explode...
list_columns = [c for c in df.columns if(isinstance(df[c][0], list))]
# ... and go for it!
df = df.explode(list_columns)

print(df.head(10))
```

That should be more efficient than exploding multiple times.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion definitely looks more efficient. I may have spoke to soon on my initial approach as adjusting to your suggestion bringing to the surface that I have variable length elements and thus explode won't work when exploding them all in parallel. Any thoughts on an efficient way to over come this?

Answer (score 0):

For instance suppose we have the following dataframe (please give an example next time) :

```
  col1  col2       col3 col4
0    a     1  [1, 2, 3]    x
1    b     2  [4, 5, 6]    y
2    c     3  [7, 8, 9]    z
```

**Proposed code**

You should vectorize for process acceleration

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3],
    'col3': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    'col4': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
})

# Function to explode a column if it contains lists
def explode_list_column(s):
    # checks if serie passed in parameter contains a list
    if any(isinstance(x, list) for x in s):
        return pd.Series(s.explode(), name=s.name)
    # No change
    return s

# Apply the function to all columns and concatenate the results
df_exploded = pd.concat([df[c].pipe(explode_list_column) for c in df], axis=1)

print(df_exploded.reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
  col1  col2 col3 col4
0    a     1    1    x
1    a     1    2    x
2    a     1    3    x
3    b     2    4    y
4    b     2    5    y
5    b     2    6    y
6    c     3    7    z
7    c     3    8    z
8    c     3    9    z
```

**Note on checking list strategy :**

maybe you could explode without checking if serie contains a list. Thus every column would be exploded.

Or you could just check for the first element like this

```py
if isinstance(s.iloc[0], list):
```

Every approach has it pros and cons, speed depends on the structure of your data :
ie if you have lists on every columns, few or not at all and dataframe length too

My advice : make some speed test on every approach

Comment: Good suggestions, the 'axis=1' is problematic though as there are dups values (which I can not drop any of them) and it errors out with 'ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels'

Comment: you may have duplicated indexes. Why not try to put your indexes as a column with `reset_index()` before doing the calculus ?